# Use jquery to make sure only one tab is collapsed at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for some help with setting a "rule" that only allows one tab to be collapsed at a time. So if one tab is collapsed and you try to collapse another tab, it will shut the original tab.

This is what the DIV looks like when the tab is shut. Pay attention to the .name children. The class has "collapsed" attached the anchor tag.

```
   <tbody id="objective" class="translate">
        <tr class="tableSubHeader active incomplete">
        <th class="icon"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#activities_21dd418d-3e6a-4afb-ae02-8f546043d9fa" class="collapsed"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>
        </th>
------------------
     <th class="name">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#activities_21dd418d-3e6a-4afb-ae02-8f546043d9fa" class="collapsed">LES B1 Module 1</a>
    </th>
---------------------
        <th class="item_progress"><div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">0% complete
                        </div></div></th>
        <th class="score"><i class="fa fa-trophy tableSubHeader active incomplete" alt="LES B1 Module 1"></i>--</th><th class="duration">--</th><th class="actions"></th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

And the dropdown:

```
<tbody id="activities" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;"></tbody>
```

This is what it looks like when its collapsed:

```
<tbody id="activities" class="panel-collapse in" style="height: auto;"></tbody>
```

CLEAN VERSION OF DOM STRUCTURE:

```
<tbody id="objective">
  <th class="name">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="collapsed">Text</a>
  </th>
</tbody>

<tbody id="activities" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height:0px;">
  ....
</tbody>

<tbody id="objective">
  <th class="name">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="collapsed">Text</a>
  </th>
</tbody>

<tbody id="activities" class="panel-collapse collapse" style="height:0px;">
  ....
</tbody>
```

Comment: Handle the collapsed state with a CSS class, then use jQuery to remove that class from all divs before applying it to the one you want collapsed.

Comment: @APAD1 makes sense what your saying. would you be able to show me an example?

Comment: @Dondada Can you explain better what you want and paste a clear code, you talk about a div, I see only a tbody, you talk about collapse, I don't see the element #accordion...

Comment: @TheLittlePig I'm basically trying to accomplish this http://jsfiddle.net/dozoisch/SMT9D/45/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how your code is structured or the desired effect you're going for, but this is the general idea:

HTML:

```
<div id="container"><div class="collapsed"><button>collapse</button></div></div>
<div id="container"><div><button>collapse</button></div></div>
<div id="container"><div><button>collapse</button></div></div>
<div id="container"><div><button>collapse</button></div></div>
<div id="container"><div><button>collapse</button></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:1em;
    width:200px;
}
    #container > div {
        height:100px;
        background:#000;
    }

button {
    color:#000;
}

.collapsed { display:none }
```

Javascript:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#container > div').removeClass('collapsed');
    $(this).parent().addClass('collapsed');
});
```

## Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqmmr6rs/1/)

Comment: I cleaned up my dom structure. Maybe you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

*Ok, Here is a table with tbody collapsible :*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/AstvtgvOmX

**Js**:

```
$('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(".collapse").removeClass('in');
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<table class="table panel-group" id="accordion2">
<thead><tr>
  <th data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">body 1</th>
  <th data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">body 2</th></tr></thead>

  <tbody id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><tr><td>1.1</td><td>1.2</td></tr></tbody>
  <tbody id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse"><tr><td>2.1</td><td>2.2</td></tr></tbody>

</table>
```